# HTML Navigation Bar only working on left side of page

Tags: html, css

I am building a website and I need help regarding the Navigation Bar I am designing. Here is my html code:

```
 <ul class="Body-P">
<nav><ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="salon.html">Notre Salon</a></li>
        <li><a href="gallerie.html">Gallerie Photo</a></li>
        <li><a href="horaires.html">Horaires</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul></nav>

 </ul>
```

And the CSS that goes with it:

```
.Body-P nav{
    background-color: #1E1E1E;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;


}

.Body-P nav ul{
    list-style:none;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.Body-P nav ul li {
    float:left;
    display:inline;


}

.Body-P nav a:link, .Body-P nav a:visited {
    color: #FFF;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    height: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Arial, 'Lucida Sans Unicode';
}

.Body-P nav a:hover, Body-P nav a:active, Body-P nav .active a:link, Body-P nav .active a:visited {
    background-color:#4A3E25;
    text-shadow: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

.Body-P nav ul li a{
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}
```

The Navigation Bar is showing without any problems but whenever I hover onto a hyperlink which is situated on the main body column of the page, it does not appear to select the hyperlink. In other words, the hover works only on the sides of the page but not in the main column. I want to know what problems are lying here and what I should do to make the hyperlink work.

Comment: Looks ok to me here http://jsfiddle.net/Tewh6/ in chrome.  Can you please explain what you mean by main body column?

Comment: Yeah, look ok for me too. Explain more which browser do you use..etc

Comment: I use Chrome 32 for testing. If it helps, I can say that the hyperlinks work only if the navigation bar is placed on the sides of the page. If it is placed in the middle of the page, the hyperlinks do not work. I'm sorry if you do not understand. I can post a picture to show if it's not understandable

Comment: You are writing invalid HTML – `UL` can have only `LI` elements as children.